# Can there be different passwords for the same account that prompts a certain reaction from Applescript?

Tags: applescript, macbook-pro, password

Can I set two passwords for the same user account so if one password is entered the computer opens up normally, and if another password is entered, Applescript locks certain applications from opening? I have a macbook that is often used by other people, and I would like to be able to give them access to only certain parts of my laptop,  not all of it

Comment: Since @tron_jones answer didn't explicitly say it.. No you can not log into the **same** account with 2 different passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Guest account and Parental Controls.  Otherwise create a separate account for each user if thats manageable and setup custom parental controls that block what you want for the separate users.

[Set up parental controls](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14414)